# On physical back button pressed how to go to device's home screen?

Tags: java, android

From mainactivity of my apps, if I press the device's back button I want the user to be taken to the device's home screen to view icons of all other apps.
I used the following code but it goes to another activity in myApps.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: have you tried removing the finish part and only leaving System.exit(0);?

Comment: Yes, I tried but no use.